# Symfony2: Dependence of getter validator on other validators

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I am using YML as my validation config format and now have the following setup:

```
properties:
    user_id:
        - NotBlank:
            message: "Please provide an user id"

    ...

getters:
    newUser:
        - "True":
            message: "You already have participated!"

    ...
```

So basically, I have two validators for my `user_id` field:

1. check, whether it is not blank
2. does some more advanced checks, (the user may not yet exist)

I don't have to validate the second condition, if the first already failed. Is there some possibility to say, that the `newUser` test depends on the `NotBlank` test?

(for example with an additional flag like `depends: user_id.NotBlank` or something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that this is currently not supported.